Angular 18 app run-time error: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).webpackContext is not a function
Trying to upgrade angular from 16 to 18 in a webapp project. In package.json, packaged related to webpack are:
{
  "@ngtools/webpack": "^18.2.3",
  "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
  "webpack": "^5.94.0"
}

After finishing grading to Angular 18, building is good but met with a run-time error:
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).webpackContext is not a function

The corresponding code is:
const context = (import.meta as any).webpackContext(
    '../../plugin/dist',
    { recursive: true, regExp: /\.(?:ogg|mp3|swf)$/, mode: 'lazy' }
);

I tried to resolve this issue but in vain. Any advice for help? Thanks!
When I put a breakpoint to check import.meta, it does not have webpackContext property:

I did a GitHub code search and found even Angular 19 can use this:
https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/36fa0d2c88555ca12df717eda714570f05197d08/src/assets/stack-blitz/src/test.ts#L17
But I did not find any webpack related package or config in the code...
[Solution] I have got the solution to fix this error: in angular.json change builder from "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application" to "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" and change "browser" property to "main".

I believe webpack has been removed so try that and see if it works.

@Grantmitchell Thanks for the comment: it was working in angular 16 without any special config for webpack, and seems there is no config file for webpack in the code but works in angular 16. So i wonder what the special change is for angular 18, or maybe it's due to angular 17 which removes webpack: Angular 17 brought a significant shift in its build process by introducing ESBuild as the default build tool for new projects, gradually moving away from Webpack.

It did not report error when upgraded to Angular 17 but does not work in Angular 18 any more.
